# Convert string with NaNs to int in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, all the values are strings. Some are 'None's, and the rest are integers but in string format, such as '123456'. How can I convert all 'None's to np.nan, and others to integers, like, 123456.

```
df = {'col1': ['1', 'None'], 'col2': ['None', '123']}
```

Convert df to:

```
df = {'col1': [1, NaN], 'col2': [NaN, 123]}
```

Comment: Is `df` a dataframe or a dictionary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
print(df.replace('None', np.nan).astype(float))
```

Output:

```
   col1   col2
0   1.0    NaN
1   NaN  123.0
```

You have to use `replace`.

P.S. if `df` is a dictionary, convert it first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Comment: Thank you, but how about the integer string? Will they be automatically converted to  float numbers?

Comment: @TingWang Edited mine, now they will :-)

Comment: Just a minor note, since this is now the accepted answer: it converts the numeric data to floats, not integers (as requested in the OP).

Answer (score 4):

You can convert your columns to [Nullable Integer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) type (new in 0.24+):

```
d = {'col1': ['1', 'None'], 'col2': ['None', '123']}
res = pd.DataFrame({
    k: pd.to_numeric(v, errors='coerce') for k, v in d.items()}, dtype='Int32')
res

   col1  col2
0     1   NaN
1   NaN   123
```

With this solution, numeric data is converted to integers (but missing data remains as NaN):

```
res.to_dict()
# {'col1': [1, nan], 'col2': [nan, 123]}
```

---

On older versions, convert to `object` when initialising the DataFrame:

```
res = pd.DataFrame({
    k: pd.to_numeric(v, errors='coerce') for k, v in d.items()}, dtype=object)
res

  col1 col2
0    1  NaN
1  NaN  123
```

It is different from the nullable types solution above—only the representation changes, not the actual data.

```
res.to_dict()
#  {'col1': [1.0, nan], 'col2': [nan, 123.0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ['1', 'None'], 'col2': ['None', '123']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d).replace("None", value=pd.np.nan).astype(float)
```

---

```
   col1   col2
0   1.0    NaN
1   NaN  123.0
```

---

```
col1    1 non-null float64
col2    1 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
```

Comment: The data type is still object, with the numbers being strings.

Comment: They are still strings after your edit. Run `result.values.tolist()` to take a look...